# Error al subir imagen con DropZone y Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, dropzone

Estoy montando un proyecto (en PHP - Laravel) y tengo diseñado un sistema para subir imágenes al servidor utilizando DropZone. El proceso de carga de la imagen es correcto, y cuando termina, asigno el valor al div escondido que tengo para poderlo capturar más tarde al guardar la información del usuario. Además, veo la imagen cargada en el cuadro. Sin embargo, **no puedo eliminarla** (la cruceta no funciona) y cuando me pongo encima, **aparece un mensaje de error genérico**.

En la consola, además, me aparece que la ruta es MethodNotAllowed, a pesar de que en la clase de enrutamiento está puesto correctamente.

Y este es el código de la vista:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"> 
        <div class="m-portlet__body m-portlet--primary" data-portlet="true" m-portlet="true">
            {{ Html::ul($errors->all()) }}

            {{ Form::open(array('url' => '#', 'id'=>'form_alta_empresa', 'files' =>true,'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')) }}

            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                <div class="col-12 ml-auto">
                    <h4 class="m-form__section">
                        {{Tr('Foto perfil')}}
                    </h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="example-text-input"><b>Foto:</b></label>
                    <div class="m-dropzone dropzone dz-clickable" id="m-dropzone-foto" action="{{ route('configusuarios.fotoUpload') }}">
                        <div class="m-dropzone__msg dz-message needsclick">
                            <h3 class="m-dropzone__msg-title">Arrastra la imagen.</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="dropzone-foto" name="dropzone-foto" type="hidden" value="">
                </div>
            </div>

            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y este el script que pone la imagen cargada:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#m-dropzone-foto", function() {
      $("#dropzone-foto").val($("#m-dropzone-foto .dz-image > img").attr("src"));
    });
  })
</script>
```

Función "FotoUpload":

```
public function fotoUpload(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        try {
            $mime = $image->getMimeType();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::warning('FotoUpload - Mime not found');
            $mime = "image/jpeg";
        }
        Log::info('FotoUpload - Mime: ' . $mime);

        $data = file_get_contents($image);
        $data = base64_encode($data);

        if ($data) {
            Log::info('FotoUpload - 1');
            return "1";
        } else {
            Log::info('FotoUpload - 0');
            return "0";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error('FotoUpload: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Registro de la clase de enrutamiento:

```
Route::post('altausuarios/fotoUpload', ['uses' => 'usersController@fotoUpload', 'as' => 'configusuarios.fotoUpload']);
```

Y este, el resultante una vez la imagen está cargada en el control:

[image: Error_Imagen]

Y el error de la consola:

[image: Error_Consola]

También pongo la captura con el mensaje del log, pero tampoco aporta mucho...

[image: Log]

`[2020-02-11 08:48:26] local.ERROR: Handler - Render - URL: http://nombredominio/altausuarios/fotoUpload - Referer: http://nombredominio/users/profile - Unknown error`

A ver si alguien se ha encontrado con esta situación y me pudiera ayudar.

Saludos,

Comment: Revisa el log y dinos que devuelve. Sin más información es difícil saber que está pasando y añade también el código de del método implicado `usersController@fotoUpload`. A parte de eso y como recomendación los controladores y en general las clases, suelen nombrarse en PascalCase.

Comment: Hola Xerif. Edito poniendo el código de la función. A ver si puedo revisar el log...

Comment: Al ver tu codigo noto que no tienes una etiqueta `form` con `multipart/form-data` o una `input file` con name `file`, y en tu codigo `php` quieres obtener un `file`, la verdad no sé de que forma estas utilizando la libreria, pero hasta donde veo no tienes nada de codigo funcional.

Comment: Hola Shassain. Disculpa, he puesto el código entero de la vista para que veas el `form`

Comment: @Ferran cómo te indica el compañero debes decirle al formulario que admita archivos, revisa la documentación de LaravelCollective: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html#opening-a-form simplemente añade `'files' => true` dentro del array de open.

Comment: @Xerif, he editado el código para añadir `'files' =>true,'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'` dentro del array de open y nada, sigue el error... :(

Comment: Estás tratando de adivinar, lo mejor es ver el log de errores para saber exactamente lo que está pasando, si no lo entiendes, pega el mensaje de error completo aquí para ver si podemos ayudar.

Comment: Como te hemos indicado revisa el log, por defecto laravel lo guarda en `storage/logs/` revisa los archivos que tengas ahi, si ves que hay muchos errores en el/los archivos, eliminalo y vuelve a reproducir el error. Tambien puedes revisar los logs de apache.

Comment: Como ya varios lo han dicho, el error no es de Dropzone, el error está en el controlador usersController, en el método fotoUpload.

Comment: He añadido el mensaje del log, pero tampoco aporta mucho...

Comment: Otra cosa que me he percatado debugando, es que nunca llega a la función FotoUpload. Por mucho que tenga un breakpoint allí, no pasa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que necesites poner el token de seguridad

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Yo suelo usar Dropzone dentro de los tags de Formulario.
Si no te funciona, puedes probar en añadir "_token" en los parámetros de la petición directamente.

Comment: Hola Gerard. Pero si te fijas, la llamada la hago directamente cuando hago el `$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#m-dropzone-foto", function()` , no tengo forma de asignar el token de ningún modo...

Comment: El usuario está utilizando LaravelCollective que ya añade el token automáticamente

Comment: Correcto Gerard, era eso. Lo que he hecho ha sido utilizar la libreria Dropzone.js (descartar la de Laravel) y sobreescribir la llamada del Dropzone por un script de inicialización. Como veía que seguía sin funcionar, he añadido el token a la cabecera (el error se quejaba de TokenMismatch) y ya está, ya carga la imagen sin el error. Gracias!

Comment: Perfecto! Me había dejado descolocado el comentario anterior, este problema suele suceder. Para el tema de CORS, hay varios paquetes para Laravel para añadir excepciones. Si desarrollas APIs en algún momento llegarás a encontrarte con ese problema. Saludos